# Remove substring that starts with SOT and ends EOT, from string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a program that reads certain strings from memory. The strings contain, for the most part, recognizable characters. At random points in the strings however, "weird" characters appear. Characters I did not recognize. By going to a site that allows me to paste in Unicode characters to see what they are, I found that a selection of the "weird" characters were these:

- \x{1} SOH, "start of heading", ctrl-a
- \x{2} SOT, "start of text"
- \x{3} EOT, "end of text"
- \x{7} BEL, bell, ctrl-g
- \x{13} dc3, device control three, ctrl-s
- \x{11} dc1, device control one, ctrl-q
- \x{14} dc4, device control four, ctrl-t
- \x{1A} sub, substitute, ctrl-z
- \x{6} ack, acknowledge, ctrl-f

I wanted to parse my strings to remove these characters. What I found out though, by looking at the strings, was that all the unwanted characters were always surrounded by the SOT and EOT, respectively.

Therefore, I am thinking that my question is: How can I remove, from a string, all occurrences of substrings that starts with SOT and ends with EOT?

---

**Edit: Attempt at Solution**

Using ideas from @RagingCain I made the following method:

```
    private static string RemoveInvalidCharacters(string input)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var start = input.IndexOf('\u0002');
            var end = input.IndexOf('\u0003', start);

            if (start == -1 || end == -1) break;

            Console.WriteLine(@"Start: " + start + @". End: " + end);
            var diff = end - start;
            input = input.Remove(start, diff);
        }
        return input;
    }
```

It does the trick, thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Any attempts? And by the way - in your samples not every line contains something surrounded by SOT & EOT - but every line contains some unprintable chars.

Comment: how does an Invalid string look like ?

Comment: Yes, I first tried to look into using some regex in a String.Replace method, but it did not seem to solve my issue. Then I thought maybe I search for \x{3}, but it did not find it in the string. In the writeLine is shows as an upside down L

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I have not provided an example of a string, those bullets are each an example of a character that would appear in the strings. Each bullet is one character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex would be your solution and should work fine. You would assign these characters to the **Pattern** and you can use the sub-method ***Match*** or even just ***Replace*** them with whitespace " ", or just cut them from the string all together by using "".

Regex.Replace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Regex.Match: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk1x0726(v=vs.110).aspx

Regex example:

```
 public static void Main()
 {
   string input = "This is   text with   far  too   much   " + 
                  "whitespace.";
   string pattern = "\\s+";
   string replacement = " ";
   Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
   string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

   Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
   Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);                             
 }
```

I know the difficulty though of not being able to "see" them so you should assign them to Char variables by Unicode itself, add them to the pattern for replace.

Char Variables: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx

Unicode for Start of Text:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0002/index.htm

Unicode for End of Text:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0003/index.htm

To apply to your solution:
Does string contain SOT, EOT.
If true, remove entire string/sub-string/SOT or EOT.

It maybe easier to split original string into a string[], then go line by line... it's difficult to parse through your string without knowing what it looks like so hopefully I provided something that helps ^.^

Comment: Thanks Cain, this is really helpful. I was thinking I could write a recursive method that searches for the index of the first occurrence of SOT, and index of first occurrence of EOT, then remove them and everything in-between, then feed the remaining text back into the method. What do you think? By the way, would it be "\u0002" i search for? Or is it "\\u0002", with double slash?

Comment: If it was me, I would assign my char variable in unicode.  I would convert my string into a character array.  Then traverse through this character array, find where SOT begins, find where EOT ends.  Now I have a starting point and an end index to create a new array, adding the characters from the first array but skipping that entire segment.  This could be recursive, and the function stops when no more SOT/EOTs are detected.

Comment: Oh it's also char a = '\u0002'.  Single quotes.