# Remove control characters sequence from string EOT comma ETX

Tags: c#, xml

I have some xml files where some control sequences are included in the text: EOT,ETX(anotherchar)
The other char following EOT comma ETX is not always present and not always the same.
Actual example:

```
<FatturaElettronicaHeader xmlns="">
</F<EOT>‚<ETX>èatturaElettronicaHeader>
```

Where `<EOT>` is the 04 char and `<ETX>` is 03. As I have to parse the xml this is actually a big issue.
Is this some kind of encoding I never heard about?

I have tried to remove all the control characters from my string but it will leave the comma that is still unwanted.
If I use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(file);` the unwanted characters will be replaced with a '?' that is easy to remove but it will still leave some unwanted characters causing parse issues:

`<BIC></WBIC>` something like this.

```
string xml = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(file);
xml = new string(xml.Where(cc => !char.IsControl(cc)).ToArray());
```

I hence need to remove all this kind of control character sequences to be able to parse this kind of files and I'm unsure about how to programmatically check if a character is part of a control sequence or not.

Comment: Are you able to change the source system (the one generating the XML) to fix the bug on its side?

Comment: No, unfortunately the source system is an API from another company. I am not sure what this kind of characters are used for..

Comment: Which enconding is used in the xml? Example: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="????" />`

Comment: What about `String.Replace`? Is there some pattern where these characters appear? For instance, always in the start of the line.

Comment: I updated the answer, I solved the issue

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer, not in the question (and then mark it as the answer).

Comment: [XML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets) documents cannot contain the codepoints U+0003 or U+0004. Perhaps the files are [XML 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#charsets) documents.

Comment: the documents are headed with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
U+0003 and U+0004 are not relevant to the document content. Fortunately I already solved removing them. That's another confirmation that the source is wrong but I can't change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find out that there are 2 wrong patterns in my files: the first is the one in the title and the second is `EOT<`.
In order to make it work I looked at this thread: [Remove substring that starts with SOT and ends EOT, from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215808/remove-substring-that-starts-with-sot-and-ends-eot-from-string)

and modified the code a little

```
private static string RemoveInvalidCharacters(string input)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var start = input.IndexOf('\u0004');
                if (start == -1) break;
                if (input[start + 1] == '<')
                {
                    input = input.Remove(start, 2);
                    continue;
                }
                if (input[start + 2] == '\u0003')
                {
                    input = input.Remove(start, 4);
                }
            }
            return input;
        }
```

A further cleanup with this code:

```
static string StripExtended(string arg)
        {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(arg.Length); //Max length
            foreach (char ch in arg)
            {
                UInt16 num = Convert.ToUInt16(ch);//In .NET, chars are UTF-16
                //The basic characters have the same code points as ASCII, and the extended characters are bigger
                if ((num >= 32u) && (num <= 126u)) buffer.Append(ch);
            }
            return buffer.ToString();
        }
```

And now everything looks fine to parse.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay in responding,
but in my opinion the root of the problem might be an incorrect decoding of a p7m file.
I think originally the xml file you are trying to sanitize was a .xml.p7m file.
I believe the correct way to sanitize the file is by using a library such as Buoncycastle in java or dotnet and the class CmsSignedData.

```
                CmsSignedData cmsObj = new CmsSignedData(content);
                if (cmsObj.SignedContent != null)
                {
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        cmsObj.SignedContent.Write(stream);
                        content = stream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
```